# Firefox Extension - Sort by Domain

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, browser-tabs

Like many of you I overuse tabs in Firefox, currently I've about 180 open tabs (my record is ~ 800) and that reduces my productivity since I'm always browsing between them to find the one I need, Closy helps to do some cleaning up but I'm missing a "order tabs by domain" like feature.

What is the less resource hungry extension that provides me such a feature and is compatible with the latest version of Firefox?

Many Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**[Group/Sort Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5627)**

> Group your tabs by
>   **hostname**.
>
> Sort your tabs by last opened date,
>   **hostname**, or last browsed date.
>   Intelligently handles the
>   opening/restoration of multiple tabs
>   at once, only sorting when the URL of
>   all opened tabs is known.
>
> Sorts tabs immediately upon navigating
>   to a different URL, prior to full page
>   load.
>
> Tabs can be manually moved into other
>   groups.

download the latest version here: [Group/Sort Tabs 2.0](http://bitbucket.org/chrisgalpin/group-sort-tabs/downloads/) (works with 3.5.x)

[image]

Comment: +1, perfect. This is the one I was trying to locate. My usual method is to keep minimal tabs open which is why this addon was lost on me.

Comment: Hmmm, can't recollect if the grouping actually allowed stacks rather than proximity like this screen shoot... maybe, that was just what I wished for at the time `:-)`

Comment: This seems great but I'm having a really hard time sorting any tab with Firefox 3.5.3.

Comment: well, the screenshot above is taken from FF 3.5.3, works fine for me.

Answer (score 0):

[**Tab Kit**](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/tab-kit/) !

> - Group tabs, by domain or opener (parent) tab, manually or
>     automatically
> - Vertical tab tree (with splitter), like Tree Style Tab
> - Multi-row tabs
> - **Sort tabs, by address, last loaded, last viewed, order of creation, origin
>     or title**
> - Control new tab position and close order
> - Easily duplicate tabs and groups and copy/move them between windows by
>     dragging
> - Scrollwheel tab switch
> - 'Mouse rocker' to go back/forward in history
> - Highlight unread tabs (and emphasise current tab)
> - Scrollbar instead of scroll arrows in over-long Bookmarks and All Tabs
>     popups
> - Open Selected Links feature
> - Switch tabs on hover
> - Options for urls, searches and/or bookmarks to open in new tabs by
>     default

(I don't know why they use such low resolution examples, it makes it look like a horrible annoying toolbar sometimes, but it really isn't. You can turn the "stacking" feature shown here, off.):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This [Tab Kit](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/5447) extension might help. Thought, I do not remember the exact small addon that could just collect tabs by domains into stacks of tabs (like Windows taskbar does).

Answer (score 0):

Not a solution, more a suggestion. Yeah, things like Tabkit are great, but could I suggest a slightly more organised system? Maybe a separate FF window for different applications- news, communication, development, research,... Or greater use of (grouped) bookmarks perhaps. Just an idea of course and feel free to ignore it, but I reckon that the best organiser is the human brain!

Comment: See [How to sort tabs into separate firefox windows based on the domain name?](http://superuser.com/q/345749/103551) (No solution found.)