# How to sort tabs into separate firefox windows based on the domain name?

Tags: firefox, browser-addons, browser-tabs

I'd like to see all my tabs from a particular domain in the same firefox window, even if I open a link to that domain from a different window (with open link in a new tab)  or from an external application. Is there a firefox extension for this?

Answer (score -1):

[Sort Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sort-tabs/?src=search) is a restartless add-on with only one small js that does the work. It only sorts in one window and per title, though, so i tried to quickly find an API reference and modify it while Firefox is running, but failed for now.

[Sort Tabs By ...](http://codeoptimism.net/2007/08/31/sorttabsby-firefox-extension), [Group/Sort Tabs](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/groupsort-tabs/), and [Tab Kit](https://addons.mozilla.org/nl/firefox/addon/tab-kit/) almost work like we want, but they're all incompatible with Firefox 11.

Comment: None of the firefox extensions listed work with current firefox version.