# Is there way to sort tabs in Firefox?

Tags: firefox

Is there way to sort tabs in Firefox? That is, given a set of tabs, press a button to sort a group of tabs (e.g., by url). It shouldn't be always sorted, only when the button is pressed. Also, it'd be helpful if a subset of tabs could be specified.

Comment: Possible Dupe of https://superuser.com/questions/41325/firefox-extension-sort-by-domain?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, no.

However, you might be interested in using the "Tab Groups" feature, which lets you organize your tabs, manually, into multiple groups between which you can switch. To use this feature, click the tab group button (four rectangles) at the far right of the tab bar (alternatively, hit <kbd>command</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> on Mac or <kbd>control</kbd>-<kbd>shift</kbd>-<kbd>E</kbd> on Windows/Linux).

You can read more [here](http://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/what-are-tab-groups).

Answer (score 1):

There is the [Sort Tabs add-on](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/sort-tabs/) - not as powerful as what you described, but it's better than nothing. Allows to sort tabs by title, works very well for me.

Comment: No longer on addons.mozilla.org

Answer (score 1):

For the latest firefox (104.0.2 as of this answer), you can use [Sort Tabs Advanced](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sort-tabs-advanced/) extension. It will allow you to sort tabs by url, domain, title and last access. There is also an option to always automatically keep tabs sorted.

Answer (score 0):

There is a mention they added sort tabs submenu into Firefox 'triple bar' button in 2017, but I cannot find it in Firefox 78.0.1 64bit. Seems removed later.
Thought, I found a great opportunity to `Ctrl-click` and Shift-click tabs like in file explorer, then either put them into bookmark folder in one swoop, move to separate browser **window** (very handy for current session - but **dangerous** in case of power blackout - browsers only restore session in the '1st' window; you loose the rest unless you have automatic session recovery addons installed, such as thegreatsuspender; which is also not fail-proof btw), or send to another device (if firefox sync is activated).